# How to add a link between two word?

Tags: hyperref, links

I want to be able to click one word A, and then go to word B. It would be good if this was two way. If I click on word B, I go to word A too.

I tried:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Word A \ref{GoTO}.

\newpage

Word B \label{GoTO}

\end{document}
```

But in the generated `.pdf` file, there isn't any link between word A and B.

Answer (score 12):

One way: Explicit `\hypertarget` and `\hypertarget` commands.

`\hypertarget{labelhere}{\hyperlink{labelthere}{some text}}`

and exchanging for the other target:

`\hypertarget{labelthere}{\hyperlink{labelhere}{some other text}}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{wordA}{\hyperlink{wordB}{Word A}}

\newpage

\hypertarget{wordB}{\hyperlink{wordA}{Word B}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I omitted a screen shot in this case